# MongoDB: mixing $all and $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection "items" of 5 items, each of which has an id and an array

```
{ _id: ObjectId("51c21bec162c138d9d0001a7"), 
    tags: [ { name: "a", type: "tag" }, { name: "b", type: "tag" }, { name: "c", type: "note" } ] 
}
{ _id: ObjectId("51c21ca22c69904840000178"), 
    tags: [ { name: "a", type: "tag" }, { name: "d", type: "tag" }, { name: "c", type: "note" } ] 
}
{ _id: ObjectId("51c21cc1478cf6691a0001b4"), 
    tags: [ { name: "d", type: "tag" }, { name: "b", type: "tag" }, { name: "c", type: "note" } ] 
}
{ _id: ObjectId("51c22292162c13b1ff000222"), 
    tags: [ { name: "a", type: "tag" }, { name: "d", type: "tag" }, { name: "e", type: "note" } ] 
}
{ _id: ObjectId("51c222e926d602a57d0001d8"), 
    tags: [ { name: "a", type: "tag" }, { name: "d", type: "note" }, { name: "c", type: "note" } ] 
}
```

**The goal here is to return all items which have tags 'a' and 'd', where the tags are of the type 'tag'.** You might have thought this would do it:

```
find({"tags.name":{"$all":["a","d"]}, "tags.type":'tag'})
```

returns 3 docs, which is wrong, but I have learnt that this query does an or. So then I try to use '$elemMatch' to do this, in what I thought was the most intuitive way, but

```
find({"tags":{"$elemMatch":{'name':{'$all':["a","d"]}, "type":'tag'}}})
```

returns no docs.

The same query, if I only want the items tagged 'a' works:

```
find({"tags":{"$elemMatch":{'name':{'$all':["a"]}, "type":'tag'}}})
```

presumably because $all gets mapped to something like $eq.

**Eventually I found that the following is what I need to do for my original GOAL**:

```
find({"tags":{"$all":[{'$elemMatch':{'name':"a", "type":'tag'}}, {'$elemMatch':{'name':"d", "type":'tag'}} ]}})
```

returns the correct two docs.

But this syntax is horrible! I have to expand the array ["a", "d"] on my own into the query. What if I am writing a generic query engine and I want to say that multiple fields of the embedded doc are arrays,and I want a certain subset of values from each array?

**Is there a better way to do this? A better syntax?**

Comment: In your question is not really clear what your goal is... *"I have this 5 documents, I want to extract all documents that have {...}"* replace {...} with your actual goal

Comment: I updated the original question to make the goal clearer. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 5):

What you eventually arrived at is the correct solution. It may be an improvement to programatically construct the array of `$elemMatch` rules.

Consider the following python:

```
match_rules = []
for tag in query_tags:
  match_rules.append({
    '$elemMatch': {
      'name': tag
      'type': 'tag'
    }
  })

collection.find({"tags":{"$all": match_rules}})
```

Comment: it worked for me! I have a situation that is a little bit different an array of subdocuments (shifts) with an array of subdocuments (applications) inside of it. I want to return the document if there there is a shift with no application for a specific user. I could achieve this using the following query:
{
        'shifts': {
          $not: {
            $all: [
              {
                applications: {
                  $elemMatch: {
                    user: userId
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }

Answer (score 0):

```
var nm = ['a', 'b']
find({$nor:[{"tags":{'$elemMatch':{'name':{$in: nm}, "type":'tag'}}}]})
```

will solve your problem. I have verified it.